# Visual Studio 2015 добавляет лишний Resources1.Designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я редактирую содержимое ресурсов вручную в студии. После этого проект перестаёт собираться, причина - Студия добавляет в проект новый файл Resources1.Designer.cs. Т.к. один файл Resources.Designer.cs уже есть, студия ругается. Приходится после каждого редактирования файла ресурсов удалять этот Resources1.Designer.cs, после чего проект нормально собирается. Этот эффект проявлялся не сразу, не после создания проекта, а через некоторое время (пару недель).
Кто знает, почему студия добавляет дополнительный файл Resources1.Designer.cs, и как это дело пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проверьте, что содержится в файле проекта (.csproj)

Если в теге `LastGenOutput` указано `Resources1`, например, так:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

То уберите единицу:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло - ваш метод работает